# How to write equations in beamer?

Tags: math-mode, errors, equations, pdftex, amsmath

I'm having errors when I try to write an equation with `beamer` package. The rest of the document works fine, so I'm only posting the relevant part :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
    f(x) = y
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this, I get the following error :

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "myFile".tex    
Trying to make PK font mathkerncmssi10 at 657 DPI...    
Running miktex-makemf.exe...    
miktex-makemf: The mathkerncmssi source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...    
miktex-makepk    
: PK font mathkerncmssi10 could not be created.    
Process exited with error(s)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

**P.S.** I'm using MiKTeX and TeXstudio on 64-bit Windows 7. I'm sure the ams* packages are installed correctly, they are working for other document types. So maybe I'm missing some additional packages for beamer?

Comment: Works out of the box with TL 2015 on Linux. I am not sure this is connected to `beamer` at all

Comment: Strange.. I expect it to work too. Nothing fancy :) But it doesn't. I tried compiling exactly the same thing in the question. Still gives the same error.

Comment: Did you try it with `article` (just for testing?)

Comment: I wrote many articles before, it was working. Let me try again though. It is working

Comment: I use the AMS packages for math, they pull in their own font handling. Haven't seen similar messages in a *long* time.

Comment: So nobody can reproduce this? :/ Let me try a reset..

Comment: No problem under MiKTeX 64 bit here. Just in case: run `updmap.exe` from the command line. It seems MiKTeX doesn't find the type 1 version of the fonts, and tries to make bitmaps.

Comment: @Bernard It worked! Though it didn't write anything into the console, after I ran it, now it's compiling. Thank you very much! I will accept if you post this as an answer. Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may happen that some vector fonts, albeit regularly installed via MiKTeX Package Manager, are not mentioned in the databases of type 1 fonts (`dvips.map` and the like) so that MiKTeX tries to make bitmaps fonts.

To circumvent this problem, you should try running `updmap.exe` from the command line, both as administrator and as user.

Comment: I had the same problem, solved in the same manner